# Omit record in group if another record is present in same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to remove a record from a group of results, if there is a record with a certain value within the same group. I tried to adapt my complex problem to a simple example:

```
DECLARE @fruits TABLE (type varchar(16), attribute varchar(16))
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('orange', 'juicy');
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('orange', 'seeds');
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('orange', 'pit');
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('apple', 'juicy');
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('apple', 'seeds');
INSERT INTO @fruits VALUES('apple', 'crisp');
SELECT * FROM @fruits;
```

Let's say I wanted to omit any record from my results that has an `attribute='pit'` if there is another fruit of the same type with `attribute='seeds'`.

How can I go about writing that query using SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `note exists` and a little bit of boolean logic:

```
select f.*
from @fruits f
where 
    attribute <> 'pit'
    or not exists (
        select 1 
        from @fruits f1 
        where f1.type = f.type and f1.attribute = 'seeds'
    )
```

This filters out records of attribute "pit" when the given type also has attribute "seeds".

It might be simpler to follow if the condition is expressed as a negation:

```
select f.*
from @fruits f
where not (
    attribute = 'pit'
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from @fruits f1 
        where f1.type = f.type and f1.attribute = 'seeds'
    )
```

An alternative uses window functions:

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        f.*, 
        max(case when attribute = 'seeds' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by type) has_seeds
    from @fruits f
) f
where not (attribute = 'pit' and has_seeds = 1)
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Note that \@fruit should be \@fruits though in the exists sub query

Comment: In my actual real-world query, what I'm currently representing as @fruits is a complex query with many joins. Using Exists requires me to basically duplicate that whole query, in two spots...but I'm OK with that at this point.

Comment: @MikePugs: ok, so you might want to use window functions instead. See my edit.

Comment: @MikePugs You might consider using a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (CTE) to avoid having to repeat your `@fruits` query. You can define your _complex query_ once and then have multiple references to it. The Query Optimizer treats the whole _smash_ as one big query, so performance shouldn't suffer.